# unable to mount HDD in linux but ok on windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, hard-drive, mount

When I plug my HDD on my ubuntu 14.04 computer I get the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ddepannemaecker/Seagate Expansion Drive: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1004,gid=1004,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/ddepannemaecker/Seagate Expansion Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

But it work perfectly under windows 7...

What can I do to access it in linux?

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the message?  NTFS is a proprietary Microsoft filesystem, and Windows handles it well unless there is actual corruption.  Linux handles it through an added driver, which can sometimes be a little picky if everything isn't just right.  The first step is to rule out what's in the message.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not used to using windows... and I'm not sure to understand what I should do. As I'm afraid to do something wrong, could you please confirm that I should open cmd terminal and run `chkdsk /f` and then eject and plug a second time my device ?

Comment: It sounds like you will be using a computer that boots Windows from the internal drive and the problem drive is a USB drive you plug in?  If so, the Windows drive is probably identified as C: and the USB drive as another letter, let's say D:.  You'll need to specify that drive letter in the command or chkdsk will assume you're referring to the internal drive.  In Windows, get an elevated command prompt by typing `cmd` in the search box in the main menu.  It will display all applications whose names contain cmd.  (cont'd)

Comment: Right-click on `cmd.exe` and select `Run as administrator`, and you'll get a terminal window.  Type `chkdsk d: /x` (use the drive's designated letter, I'm just assuming it's D:).  The drive must be unmounted (an internal command) for chkdsk to run, and Windows might automatically mount the drive when it sees it. The /x parameter includes the /f operations to fix any filesystem corruption, but it first unmounts the drive if it's mounted (which can be done since it's an external drive; to run chkdsk on the system drive, it needs to schedule it to run before the next boot). (cont'd)

Comment: It can take a long time to run (several hours on a big, slow drive), and it's recommended to let it run to completion rather than interrupting it, so plan for when you have the time to do that. When it's done, it can't hurt to eject and replug the drive to verify that it doesn't have a problem.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks a lot for your help, I'll let it run tonight! (it may be long as it is a 1To external drive)

Comment: @fixer1234, It work ! thanks a lot, if you want to post your indications as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS is a proprietary Microsoft filesystem, and Windows handles it well; it apparently can even handle minor corruption.  Linux handles it through an added driver, which can sometimes be a little picky if everything isn't just right. The first step is to rule out what's in the message.

As you discovered, the recommendation in the message to run chkdsk did solve the problem in your case.  Because yours is an external drive, the actual command is slightly different from the suggested `chkdsk /f`.

The drive must be unmounted for chkdsk to run.  When you do it on the system drive, chkdsk solves the problem by scheduling the run for the next boot.  With an external drive, the drive can simply be unmounted to run the test.  Using the `/x` parameter, instead of `/f`, unmounts the drive and then performs the /f fixes of any filesystem corruption.

Also, chkdsk assumes you are referring to the system drive unless you explicitly include the drive letter.  So if the external drive is designated `D:`, the actual command would be:

```
chkdsk d: /x
```

Run this from an elevated command prompt.  You can type `cmd` in the search box in the main menu, which will list the applications containing "cmd".  Right-click on `cmd.exe` and select `Run as administrator`, which will give you an elevated command prompt.

It is recommended to let chkdsk run to completion without interrupting it, so plan this for when you have the time to let it run (easily several hours on a large slow drive).

When it's done, it can't hurt to unplug the drive and plug it back in to verify that there aren't any problems.